# Vertex shaders in and out?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I've got two shaders like this:

```
const char* vertexShaderData =
"#version 450 \n" 
"in vec3 vp;"
"in vec3 color;\n"
"out vec3 Color;\n"
"void main(){"
"Color=color;"
"gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);" 
"}";

const char* fragShaderData =
"#version 410\n"
"uniform vec4 incolor;\n"
"in vec3 Color;"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main(){"
"outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);"
"}";
```

I understand that each shader is called for each vertex.

1. Where do the `in` paremters in my `vertexShaderData` get their values? In no point in the code do I specify what vp is or what color is. In the second shader, I get that the `in`value comes from the first shader's `out` value. But where do thoes inital `in`s come from?
2. About the `out` value of the `fragShaderData`: How is this value used? In other words, how does OpenGL know that this is an RGB color value and know to paint the triangle with this color?

Comment: [A rather good OpenGL tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) should explain most of what you need.

Comment: They get them from the buffers you bound to the GL context with `glbind`

Comment: @G.M. ok thanks, I was using open.gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the vertex shader,

you can use `glGetAttribLocation`in C++ to get the driver assigned location or manually set it like this: `layout (location = 0) in vec3 vp;` in GLSL to get the location for the attribute. Then you upload the data in C++ like this:

```
    // (Vertex buffer must be bound at this point)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( a ); // 'a' would be 0 if you did the latter
    glVertexAttribPointer( a, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( your vertex ), nullptr );
```

For the fragment shader,

'in' variables must match vertex shader's 'out' variables, like in your sample code `out vec3 Color; -> in vec3 Color;`

2. `gl_Position` controls where `outColor` is painted.

Answer (score 1):

1. You feed the data to the vertex shader from your OpenGL calls (in CPU). Once you compiled the program (vertex shader + fragment shader), you feed the vertex you want.
2. Different than the vertex shader, this fragment shader will run for once for EVERY pixel inside the triangle you are rendering. The outColor will be a vec4 (R,G,B,A) that "goes to your framebuffer". About the color, in theory, this is abstract for OpenGL. They are called RGBA for convenience... you can even access the same data as XYZW (it's an alias for RGBA). OpenGL will output NUMBERS to the framebuffer you desire (according the rules of color attachments, etc). In fact you will have 4 channels THAT BY THE WAY are used in the monitor to output RGB (and A used for transparency).... In other words, you can used GL programs to create triangles that will output 1 channel, or 2 channels, depending on your needs, and these channels can mean anything you need. For example, you can interpolate and YUV image, or a UV plane (2 channels). If you output these to monitor, you won't have the colors correct, once the monitor is expecting RGB, but the OpenGL concept is abroader than RGB. It will interpolate numbers for every pixel inside the triangle. That's it.